# attach C14 male power 3-pin connector to 2-wire cord

Tags: power-supply, ups, connector

I need to attach a [C14 male connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_connector#C13_and_C14_connectors) to my 2-wire cord to get power from my UPS.
should I ignore the middle pin on C14 and attach my 2 wires of my cord to left and right pins?

Answer (score 1):

anyways, I did it, and it is working..
just ignore the middle pin and connect two wires to left and right pins